# Series expression by using Puiseux series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

I wanna express this series 
$$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{4}+...+\sqrt{n}$$
as Puiseux series.

According to "Wolfram Alpha", it says $$\frac{2n^{3/2}}{3}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}+\zeta(-\frac{1}{2})+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}{24}+O((\frac{1}{n})^1)$$

Why $\frac{2n^{3/2}}{3}$ comes out?

I just come up this question during studying Stewart's *Calculus: Early Transcendentals*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{2x^{3/2}}3=\sqrt x$?

Comment: Oh... Thanks a lot!